# How can I move a project in Intellij IDEA CE 14 (OSX) without losing my settings/history?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I've been working on a project for a little while called (for example) work-example in my work directory.

I'm refactoring a bit and want to move the project from `~/code/projects/work/work-example` to `~/work/example`. However, I've found that I can't move the project directory without loosing everything. Am I just not understanding something very fundamental about **IntelliJ**?

My searches have all returned how to move projects within the root folder via the refactor function. This is not what I want to do. 
I want to just move the entire directory to a different location.

I'm running **OSX**.

Thanks so much for your time, everyone. :-)

Comment: What specifically do you mean by losing everything?  If you move the .idea folder (or the IDEA specific XML files), you *shouldn't* be losing everything...

Comment: Issue was that OSX doesn't show hidden files by default in Finder. cp -r in terminal fixed it. Chalimartines' answer helped point me in the right direction as to what was happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to move a project folder. IntelliJ stores all project settings inside in .idea folder or in *.ipr, *.iws, *.iml files. Close your IntelliJ move the project folder and then open from a new location and it's done.

Comment: Local history is still lost!

Comment: I think your local history in stored in IntelliJ IDEA settings folder (depending or IDEA version it is somewhere under your user directory). There is a cache containing local history. Maybe it got broken by moving your project. So far I don't know how to move project and keep even local history. Approach in the answer should preserve all project level settings (libraries, builds etc.)